# Extended Jersey Generated WADL: do not see jaxb classes

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey-2.0, wadl

I am struggling for a couple of days now with the following problem. 
I created a simple jersey 2 project.
Here is mine JerseyConfig

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        property(ServerProperties.WADL_GENERATOR_CONFIG, "com.platform.config.jersey.EpWadlGeneratorConfig");

        register(ProjectPolicyCounterWebService.class);
    }
}
```

also I have this generator config:

```
public class EpWadlGeneratorConfig extends WadlGeneratorConfig {

    @Override
    public List<WadlGeneratorDescription> configure() {

        return generator(WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc.class)
                .prop("applicationDocsStream", "ws/wadl/application-doc.xml")
                .generator(WadlGeneratorResourceDocSupport.class)
                .prop("resourceDocStream", "resourcedoc.xml")
                .generator(WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport.class)
                .prop("grammarsStream", "ws/wadl/application-grammars.xml")
                .prop("overrideGrammars", true)
                .generator(WadlGeneratorResourceDocSupport.class)
                .prop("resourceDocStream", "ws/wadl/resourcedoc.xml")
                .descriptions();
    }

}
```

I created appropriate resourcedoc.xml, application-grammars.xml, application-doc.xml. But my wadl for this controller

```
@GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Path("type")
    public NumberResponseType type() {
        NumberResponseType type = new NumberResponseType ();
        type.setNumbersFreeAmount(23423L);
        type.setDateResponse(new XMLGregorianCalendarImpl());
        type.setErrorList(new ErrorListType());

        return type;
    }
```

do not contain my element in response type

```
<ns2:application xmlns:ns2="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
<ns2:doc title="A message in the WADL" xml:lang="en">
This is added to the start of the generated application.wadl
</ns2:doc>
<ns2:doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 2.19 2015-06-29 13:02:58"/>
<ns2:doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:hint="This is simplified WADL with user and core resources only. To get full WADL with extended resources use the query parameter detail. Link: http://localhost:9000/api/application.wadl?detail=true"/>
<ns2:grammars>
<ns2:include href="/ws/xsd/NumberResponseType.xsd"/>
</ns2:grammars>
<ns2:resources base="http://localhost:9000/api/">
<ns2:resource path="/">
<ns2:resource path="type">
<ns2:method id="type" name="GET">
<ns2:response>
<ns2:representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
</ns2:response>
</ns2:method>
</ns2:resource>
</ns2:resource>
</ns2:resources>
</ns2:application>
```

What do I do wrong?